# Access IEx.pry from escript

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir and have been debugging my code by starting with `iex -S mix` and putting `IEx.pry` breakpoints in functions. I've now packaged some code as a command-line app (using `escript`) and am trying to invoke `IEx.pry` after running my code via the `escript` executable. However, the function is not available -- `IEx` is apparently not bundled with the executable. How can I access `IEx.pry` from my executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are strongly discouraged to do that (`escript` is considered to be a release/production entity, you are supposed to debug it till it works and release afterwards,) it’s still possible: just list [`iex`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html) in the list of applications within your project’s `mix.exs`:

```rb
def project do
  [
    app: @application,
    version: @version,
    ...,
    deps: [
      {:iex, "~> 1.6"},
      ...
    ]
  ]
end
```

And start it as a dependent application, since it’s likely [needed to be started](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.6/lib/iex/lib/iex.ex#L756):

```rb
def application do
  [
    mod: {MyApp.Application, []},
    extra_applications: ~w|iex|a
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is the best kind of answer, as it both answers my question and provides best practice guidance. I am wondering though, what is the recommended way to debug my code when I have to provide input via the command line? Or in other words, what is the recommended way to get to my `escript` main function (which is called with the command line args) without going through `escript` itself?

Comment: Whether it is main, or not main, it is just a simple function. Just call it from your tests.